# Measuring MS Access SQL query duration

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-performance, linked-tables

I'm trying to compare MS Access SQL queries for **local table** vs **linked table** 
(it is linked to an Oracle and to a SQL Server database).

I **can** get query duration when running the SQL command directly on Oracle or SQL Server, but when running the SQL in MS Access, I don't know how to capture the query duration.

Is there a way to get the query duration when running a SQL command **inside** MS Access?

Thanks. :-)

Comment: You might like to look at Showplan : http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewtopic.php?f=95&t=9011&sid=e318b1c88a581b6ee59e126ddbf7df38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

1. Record in a variable the actual time.
2. Create a recordset with data source pointing to your query/view/table
3. Open the recordset (eventually you may check the recordcount)
4. Record in another variable the actual time
5. DateDiff between 1. amd 4.

Comment: I could send you an example tomorrow if you want.

Comment: I've already did something similar, but the thing I really want to know is to understand the amount of time that `MS Access` is doing on "his side", while using linked table. To be more specific, I'm looking for a way to investigate deeper into step 3 in your answer...

Comment: open a new ado connection to the corresponding database, open a recordset based on this connection, with something like "select 1 from dual" for data source and investigate datediff.

Comment: don't forget the time necessary to transfer the data between database server and local application. if the connection with your server is poor and you have big amount of data, then it's going to take a lot of time to transfer the data.

Comment: Sure. I'm aware of that. that's why I'm running my MDB file on the server itself to test the actual communication speed between MDB and the DB (without network).

Comment: Well, then the ms access effort is just the same as ado effort. Access doesn't do anything special besides ado. If your application is on the same machine with the DB, then I think your test is irrelevant. The time consumed by ms access to connect to db and send requests is just to short and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Access does not provide that sort of information, unlike server databases.

You could use a Form Timer and get an idea of the duration, but with linked tables a lot of that depends on the network, server overhead, etc.